# how to get numeric cell value from excel using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i want to get the numeric value from a excel to gmail login page
what is the code for getting numeric cell value

Please advise me

Thanks & Regards 
srinu

Answer (score 0):

what is u r jar file JXL or POI

If it is POI use getNumaricCellValue() of that particular cell. It is for Numaric cell only
If it is JXL use .getCell(col, row).getContents(); it will return string only.It does not depends on the type of cell.

Comment: i am using Poi jar file but still having problem while using cell value in the password filed a red line is showing at the sendkeys mesthod

Answer (score 0):

Red line may be due to other validation reasons, like Is password accepts numaric data or not,      and check the minimum and maximum size password textbox accepts and all.

TO read the data from excel sheet that method is enough.